# E/ERROR :: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

this is my first time asking question in here, and I'm sorry my English isn't good. I get this error every time I do POST and I can't to to another activity. I don't know how to solve it.

```
E/ERROR :: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
```

this is my model

```
public class Experience implements Serializable { 
    @SerializedName("id") 
    @Expose 
    private String id; 

    @SerializedName("idKandidat") 
    @Expose 
    private String idKandidat; 

    @SerializedName("companyName") 
    @Expose 
    private String companyName; 

    @SerializedName("monthJoin") 
    @Expose 
    private Integer monthJoin; 

    @SerializedName("yearJoin") 
    @Expose 
    private Integer yearJoin; 

    @SerializedName("stillWorking") 
    @Expose 
    private Boolean stillWorking; 

    @SerializedName("monthResign") 
    @Expose 
    private Integer monthResign; 

    @SerializedName("yearResign") 
    @Expose 
    private Integer yearResign; 

    @SerializedName("posisionAs") 
    @Expose 
    private String posisionAs; 

    @SerializedName("descriptionJob") 
    @Expose 
    private String descriptionJob;

    public Experience() {
    }
    
    public Experience(String id, String idKandidat, String companyName, Integer monthJoin, Integer yearJoin, Boolean stillWorking, Integer monthResign, Integer yearResign, String posisionAs, String descriptionJob) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.idKandidat = idKandidat;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.monthJoin = monthJoin;
        this.yearJoin = yearJoin;
        this.stillWorking = stillWorking;
        this.monthResign = monthResign;
        this.yearResign = yearResign;
        this.posisionAs = posisionAs;
        this.descriptionJob = descriptionJob;
    }
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public Experience withId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }
    
    public String getIdKandidat() {
        return idKandidat;
    }
    
    public void setIdKandidat(String idKandidat) {
        this.idKandidat = idKandidat;
    }
    
    public Experience withIdKandidat(String idKandidat) {
        this.idKandidat = idKandidat;
        return this;
    }
    
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    
    public Experience withCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Integer getMonthJoin() {
        return monthJoin;
    }
    
    public void setMonthJoin(Integer monthJoin) {
        this.monthJoin = monthJoin;
    }
    
    public Experience withMonthJoin(Integer monthJoin) {
        this.monthJoin = monthJoin;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Integer getYearJoin() {
        return yearJoin;
    }
    
    public void setYearJoin(Integer yearJoin) {
        this.yearJoin = yearJoin;
    }
    
    public Experience withYearJoin(Integer yearJoin) {
        this.yearJoin = yearJoin;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Boolean getStillWorking() {
        return stillWorking;
    }
    
    public void setStillWorking(Boolean stillWorking) {
        this.stillWorking = stillWorking;
    }
    
    public Experience withStillWorking(Boolean stillWorking) {
        this.stillWorking = stillWorking;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Integer getMonthResign() {
        return monthResign;
    }
    
    public void setMonthResign(Integer monthResign) {
        this.monthResign = monthResign;
    }
    
    public Experience withMonthResign(Integer monthResign) {
        this.monthResign = monthResign;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Integer getYearResign() {
        return yearResign;
    }
    
    public void setYearResign(Integer yearResign) {
        this.yearResign = yearResign;
    }
    
    public Experience withYearResign(Integer yearResign) {
        this.yearResign = yearResign;
        return this;
    }

    public String getPosisionAs() {
        return posisionAs;
    }
    
    public void setPosisionAs(String posisionAs) {
        this.posisionAs = posisionAs;
    }
    
    public Experience withPosisionAs(String posisionAs) {
        this.posisionAs = posisionAs;
        return this;
    }
    
    public String getDescriptionJob() {
        return descriptionJob;
    }
    
    public void setDescriptionJob(String descriptionJob) {
        this.descriptionJob = descriptionJob;
    }
    
    public Experience withDescriptionJob(String descriptionJob) {
        this.descriptionJob = descriptionJob;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is My Service

```
public interface ExperienceService {
    @GET("DetailExperience/get")
    Call<List<Experience>> getDetailEmergencies();

    @GET("DetailExperience/getDetailExperience")
    Call<List<Experience>> getDetailExperience();

    @GET("DetailExperience/getDetailExperience/{id}")
    Call<List<Experience>> getDetailExperience(@Path("id") String id);

    @GET("DetailExperience/getSelectedExperience/{id}")
    Call<List<Experience>> getSelectedExperience(@Path("id") String id);

    @GET("DetailExperience/getById/{id}")
    Call<List<Experience>> getById();

    @Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
    @POST("DetailExperience/save")
    Call<Experience> SaveDetailExperience(@Body Experience experience);

    @GET("DetailExperience/deleted/{id}")
    Call<Experience> deleteDetailExperience(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

This is My Retrofit

```
public class APIUtils {
    private APIUtils(){

    }

    public static final String API_URL = "http://192.168.100.7:2424/api/";

    public static ExperienceService getExperienceService(){
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(API_URL).create(ExperienceService.class);
    }
}
```

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String url){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

This is My Activity

```
package com.example.rekrutmenreka;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.text.Transliterator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.rekrutmenreka.adapter.ExperienceAdapter;
import com.example.rekrutmenreka.model.Experience;
import com.example.rekrutmenreka.remote.APIUtils;
import com.example.rekrutmenreka.remote.ExperienceService;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class SelectedExperienceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExperienceService experienceService;
    String IdKandidat,IdExperience,CompanyName,PosisionAs,DescriptionJob, MonthJoin,YearJoin,MonthResign,YearResign;
    EditText edtIdKandidat,edtCompanyName,edtPosisionAs,edtDescriptionJob,edtMonthJoin,edtYearJoin,edtMonthResign,edtYearResign;
    Boolean EdtStillWorking;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    TextInputLayout txtLayoutEditExperience6, txtLayoutEditExperience7;
    SwitchCompat swEdtStillWorking;
    Button btnUpdateExperience;
    ProgressBar pbDataExperience;
    private int mYear,mMonth,mDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selected_experience);

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        IdExperience = intent.getStringExtra("IdExperience");
        pbDataExperience = findViewById(R.id.pbEditDataExperience);
        pbDataExperience.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        edtIdKandidat = findViewById(R.id.edtIdKandidat);
        edtCompanyName = findViewById(R.id.edtCompanyName);
        edtPosisionAs = findViewById(R.id.edtPosisionAs);
        edtDescriptionJob = findViewById(R.id.edtDescriptionJob);
        txtLayoutEditExperience6 = findViewById(R.id.txtLayoutEditExperience6);
        txtLayoutEditExperience7 = findViewById(R.id.txtLayoutEditExperience7);
        edtMonthJoin = findViewById(R.id.edtMonthJoin);
        edtYearJoin = findViewById(R.id.edtYearJoin);
        edtMonthResign = findViewById(R.id.edtMonthResign);
        edtYearResign = findViewById(R.id.edtYearResign);
        swEdtStillWorking = findViewById(R.id.swEdtStillWorking);

        loadData();

        edtMonthJoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                // date picker dialog
                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(SelectedExperienceActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                                /*addMonthJoin.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);*/
                                edtMonthJoin.setText(String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1));
                                edtYearJoin.setText(String.valueOf(year));
                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        edtYearJoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                // date picker dialog
                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(SelectedExperienceActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                                /*addMonthJoin.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);*/
                                edtMonthJoin.setText(String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1));
                                edtYearJoin.setText(String.valueOf(year));
                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        edtMonthResign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                // date picker dialog
                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(SelectedExperienceActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                                /*addMonthJoin.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);*/
                                edtMonthResign.setText(String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1));
                                edtYearResign.setText(String.valueOf(year));
                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        edtYearResign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                // date picker dialog
                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(SelectedExperienceActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                                /*addMonthJoin.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);*/
                                edtMonthResign.setText(String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1));
                                edtYearResign.setText(String.valueOf(year));
                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        swEdtStillWorking.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!isChecked){
                    txtLayoutEditExperience6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtLayoutEditExperience7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    txtLayoutEditExperience6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    txtLayoutEditExperience7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        btnUpdateExperience = findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateExperience);
        btnUpdateExperience.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Experience experience = new Experience();

                IdKandidat = edtIdKandidat.getText().toString();
                CompanyName = edtCompanyName.getText().toString();
                PosisionAs = edtPosisionAs.getText().toString();
                DescriptionJob = edtDescriptionJob.getText().toString();
                MonthJoin = edtMonthJoin.getText().toString();
                YearJoin = edtYearJoin.getText().toString();
                EdtStillWorking = swEdtStillWorking.isChecked();
                MonthResign = edtMonthResign.getText().toString();
                YearResign = edtYearResign.getText().toString();

                if (CompanyName.trim().equals("")){
                    edtCompanyName.setError("Tidak Boleh Kosong");
                }else if(PosisionAs.trim().equals("")){
                    edtPosisionAs.setError("Tidak Boleh Kosong");
                }else if(DescriptionJob.trim().equals("")){
                    edtDescriptionJob.setError("Tidak Boleh Kosong");
                }else if(MonthJoin.trim().equals("")){
                    edtMonthJoin.setError("Tidak Boleh Kosong");
                }else if(YearJoin.trim().equals("")){
                    edtYearJoin.setError("Tidak Boleh Kosong");
                }else if(!EdtStillWorking){
                    if (MonthResign.trim().equals("")){
                        edtMonthResign.setError("Tidak Boleh Kosong");
                    }
                    if (YearResign.trim().equals("")){
                        edtYearResign.setError("Tidak Boleh Kosong");
                    }
                }
                experience.setId(IdExperience);
                experience.setIdKandidat(IdKandidat);
                experience.setCompanyName(CompanyName);
                experience.setMonthJoin(Integer.parseInt(MonthJoin));
                experience.setYearJoin(Integer.parseInt(YearJoin));
                experience.setStillWorking(EdtStillWorking);
                if (EdtStillWorking){
                    experience.setMonthResign(0);
                    experience.setYearResign(0);
                }else{
                    experience.setMonthResign(Integer.parseInt(MonthResign));
                    experience.setYearResign(Integer.parseInt(YearResign));
                }
                experience.setPosisionAs(PosisionAs);
                experience.setDescriptionJob(DescriptionJob);

                experienceService = APIUtils.getExperienceService();
                Call<Experience> call = experienceService.SaveDetailExperience(experience);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Experience>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Experience> call, Response<Experience> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(SelectedExperienceActivity.this, "Data Berhasil Disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SelectedExperienceActivity.this, DetailExperienceActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Experience> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("ERROR : ", t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                /*insertData(experience);*/
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadData() {
        experienceService = APIUtils.getExperienceService();
        Call<List<Experience>> call = experienceService.getSelectedExperience(IdExperience);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Experience>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Experience>> call, Response<List<Experience>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    List<Experience> listEdit = response.body();
                    edtIdKandidat.setText(listEdit.get(0).getIdKandidat());
                    edtCompanyName.setText(listEdit.get(0).getCompanyName());
                    edtPosisionAs.setText(listEdit.get(0).getPosisionAs());
                    edtDescriptionJob.setText(listEdit.get(0).getDescriptionJob());
                    edtMonthJoin.setText(Integer.toString(listEdit.get(0).getMonthJoin()));
                    edtYearJoin.setText(Integer.toString(listEdit.get(0).getYearJoin()));
                    swEdtStillWorking.setChecked(listEdit.get(0).getStillWorking());
                    edtMonthResign.setText(Integer.toString(listEdit.get(0).getMonthResign()));
                    edtYearResign.setText(Integer.toString(listEdit.get(0).getYearResign()));
                    pbDataExperience.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Experience>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR : ", t.getMessage());
                pbDataExperience.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried to send via POSTMAN and the result was successfull.

This is the Logging

```
2022-12-14 21:40:19.843 552-692/system_process D/InputDispatcher: Waiting to send key to Window{cfe608e u0 com.example.rekrutmenreka/com.example.rekrutmenreka.SelectedExperienceActivity} because there are unprocessed events that may cause focus to change
2022-12-14 21:40:20.191 552-692/system_process D/InputDispatcher: Waiting to send key to Window{cfe608e u0 com.example.rekrutmenreka/com.example.rekrutmenreka.SelectedExperienceActivity} because there are unprocessed events that may cause focus to change
2022-12-14 21:40:21.250 552-692/system_process D/InputDispatcher: Waiting to send key to Window{cfe608e u0 com.example.rekrutmenreka/com.example.rekrutmenreka.SelectedExperienceActivity} because there are unprocessed events that may cause focus to change
2022-12-14 21:40:21.371 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.100.7:2424/api/DetailExperience/save
2022-12-14 21:40:21.371 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2022-12-14 21:40:21.372 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 289
2022-12-14 21:40:21.372 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
2022-12-14 21:40:21.377 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: {"companyName":"PT Mencari Cinta Sejati","descriptionJob":"Belajar Coding","id":"1063860e-e213-4d13-8f41-132e87558ffd","idKandidat":"29be4f5e-50a2-4bdd-b929-c9e796c6b7c3","monthJoin":12,"monthResign":12,"posisionAs":"Staff Marketing","stillWorking":false,"yearJoin":2020,"yearResign":2022}
2022-12-14 21:40:21.377 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: --> END POST (289-byte body)
2022-12-14 21:40:21.479 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.100.7:2424/api/DetailExperience/save (101ms)
2022-12-14 21:40:21.480 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2022-12-14 21:40:21.480 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2022-12-14 21:40:21.480 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
2022-12-14 21:40:21.480 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
2022-12-14 21:40:21.480 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 14 Dec 2022 14:40:22 GMT
2022-12-14 21:40:21.484 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: "Data Success"
2022-12-14 21:40:21.484 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (14-byte body)
2022-12-14 21:40:21.489 6662-6662/com.example.rekrutmenreka E/ERROR :: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the HTTP request to `DetailExperience/save` do not return a JSON Object, what is expected here:

```
public void onResponse(Call<Experience> call, Response<Experience> response)
```

This expected that the POST request returns a JSON with data for a Experience object.

But the log message says, the endpoint returns a quoted string:

```
2022-12-14 21:40:21.484 6662-6720/com.example.rekrutmenreka D/OkHttp: "Data Success"
```

Possible fix could be:

```
public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a json serialize/deserialize quesion , value is object , but deserialize is string.

`Data Success` is a String , not a object, you need change receive type or change backend return value  don't return a